# Amazon web services, How to start

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Started working with AWS, Have huge account of EXCEL data to be stored in AWS and need to access those data form AWS API's. Pleas help me where to start for this.

Not clear about the use case. can anyone explain me the difference between Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3), Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2), Amazon SimpleDB in simple words.

Please help me in how start from scratch.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple terms:

- S3: File Storage
- EC2: Virtual Servers (Linux or Windows)
- Simple DB: A NoSQL database. Most people use the newer DynamoDB service these days.

You really aren't giving enough information for anyone to provide detailed help. You could store the data as files in S3, and possibly query it using Athena. You could store the files on a file system on an EC2 server and run any Windows or Linux program there to work with the files. You could store the data in a relational OLTP database using the RDS service. You could store the data in an OLAP database using Redshift. You could store the data in a NoSQL database using DynamoDB. If it is an extremely large amount of data you might want to look into using the Elastic Map Reduce service to process it.

Comment: Remarkably useful for such a brief comment! and for a question that I thought was too vague to be answered.